# get client ip not load balancer ip in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to set up the system in the link on Amazon Virtual Private Cloud. 
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1H3s9O2GnM52cfKWiyt2oK92SSCEU-K1Srz5sw2uuRhU/edit?usp=sharing

My question is "any possible to let TCP server know real TCP Client's IP ?" 
I get ip always from load-balancer and no idea about how to get the ip from real client.

Very Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#proxy-protocol),

> **Proxy Protocol**
>
> The Proxy Protocol header helps you identify the IP address of a client when you use a load balancer configured for TCP/SSL connections. Because load balancers intercept traffic between clients and your back-end instances, the access logs from your back-end instance contain the IP address of the load balancer instead of the originating client. When Proxy Protocol is enabled, the load balancer adds a human-readable format header that contains the connection information, such as the source IP address, destination IP address, and port numbers of the client. The header is then sent to the back-end instance as a part of the request. You can parse the first line of the request to retrieve your client's IP address and the port number.
>
> The Proxy Protocol line is a single line that ends with a carriage return and line feed ("\r\n"). It takes the following form:
>
> `PROXY_STRING + single space + INET_PROTOCOL + single space + CLIENT_IP + single space + PROXY_IP + single space + CLIENT_PORT + single space + PROXY_PORT + "\r\n"`
>
> The following is an example of the IPv4 Proxy Protocol.
>
> `PROXY TCP4 198.51.100.22 203.0.113.7 35646 80\r\n`
>
> The Proxy Protocol line for IPv6 takes an identical form, except it begins with TCP6 and the address is in IPv6 format.
>
> The following is an example of the IPv6 Proxy Protocol.
>
> `PROXY TCP6 2001:DB8::21f:5bff:febf:ce22:8a2e 2001:DB8::12f:8baa:eafc:ce29:6b2e 35646 80\r\n`
>
> If the client connects with IPv6, the address of the proxy in the header will be the public IPv6 address of your load balancer. This IPv6 address matches the IP address that is resolved from your load balancer's DNS name that is prefixed with either ipv6 or dualstack. If the client connects with IPv4, the address of the proxy in the header is the private IPv4 address of the load balancer, which is not resolvable through a DNS lookup outside the EC2-Classic network.
>
> For information about enabling the Proxy Protocol header, see [Enable or Disable Proxy Protocol Support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html).